# how add link for object with html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

It is possible to add link to flash object? I have tried do this by two ways but it still do not work:

**First try:**

**html**

```
<div class="main_image" data-href="some link">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?=$this->baseUrl('/resources/flash/banner_cs5.swf');?>" 
    width="708" height="255" id="content_flash" style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('.main_image').click(function() {
    window.location.href($(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

**Second try:**

**html**

```
<div class="main_image" data-href="some link">
  <a href="some link" style="display:block;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:10;">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?=$this->baseUrl('/resources/flash/banner_cs5.swf');?>" 
        width="708" height="255" id="content_flash" style="visibility: visible; ">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    </object>
  </a>
</div>
```

So both do not work. How can I do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add link inside of your flash,
click event on flash element is catched by flash itself so it wont be delegated to html, so basicly you cant catch it, as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div which will work like an overlay but it is little gory.

HTML part :

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index: 1;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=""
    width="708" height="255" id="content_flash" style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
<div class="main_image" data-href="some link" style="width: 708px; height: 255px; margin-top: -255px;position:relative; z-index:99;"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery part :

```
$('.main_image').click(function() {
    window.location.href($(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

You can find an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/dybB3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="some link" target="_new" >
<div style="position:relative; z-index: 1;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=""
    width="708" height="255" id="content_flash" style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
<div class="main_image" data-href="some link" style="width: 708px; height: 255px; margin-top: -255px;position:relative; z-index:99;"></div>
</div>
</a>
```